# Angular API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, angular7, ng-build

I'm deploying angular 7 app to **Azure**, an error

> **API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory**

is appear when run `ng build --prod` even in local system when running `ng build --prod` no error found except some warning

`WARNING in Invalid background value at 9045:14. Ignoring.
WARNING in Invalid background value at 9064:14. Ignoring.
WARNING in Invalid background value at 9067:14. Ignoring.
WARNING in Invalid background value at 9070:14. Ignoring.
WARNING in Invalid background value at 9073:14. Ignoring.
WARNING in Invalid background value at 11642:14. Ignoring.`

here is the [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtvQS.png)
[image: Activity log]

here is `package.json`

[image: package.json]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` package do you have in package.json, in the devDependencies?

Comment: it's `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0"`

Comment: @WalterŁuszczyk I've added `package.json` kindly have alook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need more gb memory to compile the project in wherever that ng build happens. Either increase memory, or do the ng build in your local, and commit the dist, then in Azure you just deploy with no build step.

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've tried it and it still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the budget of type initial from 5mb in the maximum error to whatever you needed in Angular.json

[image]